# Should Stack Overflow rules against recommendation be softened when dealing with emerging tech?

Tags: discussion, scope, recommendation-questions

I *(under the name v1nce*) posted the following question
[Where can I find "books" in Apple News Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586735/where-can-i-find-books-in-apple-news-format)
which is on hold now because I asked for a recommendation and this is supposed to be prone to opinionated answers (or spam).

Yes, it is. But does this not fulfil a real need?

I'm unhappy with (but I respect) the rule of "no recommendation" for "old" tech, I'd rather find recommendations in Stack Overflow but I'm fine with asking Google because I'll find tutorials/introduction/samples easily When the tech is mature.

This is another matter with a new language (vala), file format (ANF), codec (av1) which don't have reached yet the critical mass to attract lots of devs and for which there's little or no documentation except for a reference site. This reference site is not always sufficient for edge cases, big files/bitrates.
Alternative examples could exist but be hard to find using Google.

**I think asking for a recommendation should be:**

- **Not OK when *you're new to the subject*** (and too lazy to Google for it)
- **OK when the *subject is new***

After some months such question and its answers will probably look obsolete (and maybe looks like spam) but before this happens I think it'd have really helped the devs.

PS: I know that vala and av1 are not new anymore, the proof is it's easy NOW to find resources about it.

EDIT: **I finally found an interesting answer in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751280/example-article-json-for-apple-news). Could someone comment on [why my question was considered off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586735/where-can-i-find-books-in-apple-news-format) when [the other wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751280/example-article-json-for-apple-news)**. Does it just escape moderator attention while it should have been moderated too ? The other poster was asking for reasonable example when I asked for non trivial/real worl exemple.

Comment: If the goal of the site is just to "fulfill a need" then why not allow automobile repair questions as there is a definite need for them to be answered as well? But that is not how the site works, nor how it succeeds as it also has to maintain focus. And if your proposition is accepted, who is to decide what is new and what isn't? And what programming language doesn't have new or changing properties?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: About how to decide : Maybe those who rush to downvote when they see '...recommend...' should be invited to ask themselves is it a legitimate question or just laziness ? Does googling 'introduction to X' return 500000 responses or 1 ?

Comment: @BDL thank you for the info on meaning of downvote on Meta.

Comment: @Frenchone and how do you moderate the switch from "new enough" to "not new enough"? This is HIGHLY subjective, won't be moderatable, will lead to arguments and flame war. There is indeed a need. Why does it have to be *stack* that fills that need?

Comment: Question legitimacy is an often used defense against curation.  Sure, I don't think anyone ever thinks it's not actually a legitimate problem. But just because it's legitimate doesn't make it immune to our quality standards, or curation.  *That* is what matters; as long as those standards are met, then it really doesn't matter whether you're having the problem or not.  So focus less on, "I have this problem", and more on, "How do I meet these standards?".

Comment: <EDIT> I got it wrong, it's also a bad question. As far as that goes, though, those answers are pretty bad; if those links ever die, the value is gone.

Comment: He was asking for reasonable exemple, I was asking for non trivial. The difference is subtle for me.

Comment: You know what?  Reading the other question in more depth, yeah, it's also asking for a resource, and should also be closed.  The answers are a great demonstration as to why we don't allow those types of questions.

Comment: @frenchone Suggesting edits to posts from the same person on different accounts is having those accounts interact directly, and even involves you attempting to get rep for something you shouldn't be, namely editing "your own" post.

Comment: @Servy I gained editing "recently" and I rarely used it. So it is possible I hit the edit button on the wrong post. Maybe the edit button should be labelled "suggest editing" to prevent this. Or maybe I should just stop using two accounts to prevent making mistakes like this.

Comment: _Could someone comment on why my question was considered off-topic when the other wasn't_ There's no point, really - just because one question didn't get the requisite number of views by people with the right privileges to close it, doesn't mean a question that did get those views shouldn't be closed. Judge a question against the current rules in isolation, not other questions

Comment: @Servy Ok it's more clear now., what i've done is suggesting editing for the original 'v1nce' post. Could I drop this suggestion ? This has already been reviewed and rejected by one user it's no use some others waste time on this.

Comment: @frenchone just stop doing it. The other thing you can do is ask for the accounts to be merged. Raise a mod flag.

Answer (score 24):

No.

Recommendation questions are off-topic because long experience has shown they do not mesh with our Q&A format.

They devolve into popularity contests, which undermines the meaning of the voting system we rely on to sort wheat from chaff.

The Q&A format is intended to capture and sort definitive answers to factual questions. Recommendation questions can’t invite these kinds of answers, and the kinds of answers they do invite create a mess and a disservice to the site and its users.

The litmus test isn’t “could this question help someone?”: if it were, we’d accept any question whatsoever. If you want that, try Yahoo! Answers (and while you’re there, have a look around to see [*why* this isn’t our litmus test](https://www.lipstickalley.com/threads/yahoo-answers-is-a-mess.241365/)).

I feel many Meta questions like the one you’ve asked simply fall afoul of the [Streetlight Effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect):

[image: early comic illustrating the *streetlight effect*]

They know the audience they want to address is here, and could answer their question, but they ignore the fact that *that audience is here precisely because we are selective about which questions we allow people to ask*.

In short: the light is better here, no doubt, but your keys are somewhere else.

Comment: They devolve into popularity contests : Unless they are way too many contestants (and so too many responses) I don't see what would be wrong with that. I'd take the responses with a bit of salt but generally it looks to me people are kind enough to disclaims when their response is biased.

Comment: They devolve into popularity contests : for new technology the problem is the opposite, there are not enough contestants

Comment: @frenchone The site doesn’t want biased answers. And whether they start out with few or many answers is irrelevant. It’s the conceptual mismatch between the standards and objectives of the site and the kinds of answers these Qs attract. And even if the number of answers mattered — it doesn’t, but let’s pretend — than as you yourself say, over time the # of answers will grow, making the Q temporarily useful, but the site strives to build a *canonical, lasting repository of knowledge and expertise*. We do not want temporarily useful information, we are not a forum. The answer to your Q is **no**

Comment: We do not want temporarily useful information : there are a lot of answers that were  good on their time but are now deprecated yet they are still the selected answer. I think people are clever enough not to rely only on popularity of a reponse but rather on the intrinsinc quality of the response (vs other responses)

Comment: @frenchone There is no intrinsic quality in subjective answers. There is no turning an opinion into a fact. There is no way for you to wordsmith your way around this reality. Any additional comments you make is just wasted effort: I promise you this policy will not change and any future recommendation questions will continue to be closed. That’s all that can be said on the matter, so I’m leaving it here, and will post no further replies.